# Probability-Deck of cards

Tags: probability

A deck contains 52 cards.

I draw 7. (without replacemnt)

What is the probability that amongst the seven cards, exists exactly: one club and two spades?

I assumed this was a hypergeometric question, but is it?

N=52, n=7, M=?, m=?

Comment: Ignore what the *name* of the specific distribution is (*we can look it up later*) and instead approach directly via counting techniques.  Recognize that there are $\binom{52}{7}$ equally likely possible hands of seven cards (*where order doesn't matter*).  There are $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to choose exactly one club, $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to choose exactly two spades and $\binom{26}{4}$ ways to choose exactly four more red cards (*where order doesn't matter*).  Applying multiplication principle we get the total number of "good" hands and taking the ratio gives the probability as....

Comment: As for the actual name of the distribution that arises from this situation, it is apparently called the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution), though I never bothered learning or looking up the name until now since you can just derive the formula on the spot without having to memorize it or its name.